# Tablesorter.js horizontal scroll issue when sorting

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, cross-browser, tablesorter

I am  using tablesorter.js and I have a horizontal scrollbar for the tbody and using jquery to horizontally scroll the header along with the tbody scrolling position.

The problem I am encountering is when I scroll any amount and then click sort of a field, the tbody pushes back to its initial 0 scrollLeft(0) position in IE and in Firefox the entire tbody shifts the position left to the degree of the scroll distance, it works in google Chrome as intended.

This only occurs after horizontally scrolling.

Below is the jquery bind I am using for the header to scroll with the tbody:

```
      $("tbody").bind('scroll', function () {
            var myScroll = $(this).scrollLeft();
            $(".fixedHeader").scrollLeft(myScroll);
        });
```

I am using this to try to fix the issue, still no luck.

```
        $("#scrollTable th span").bind('click', function() {
            var currentScroll = $(".fixedHeader").scrollLeft();
            $("tbody").scrollLeft(currentScroll);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that I was trying to use Knockout.js with tablesorter.js and they were in conflict. Knockout.js uses MVVM pattern and tablesorter updates the view on sort event. So both were trying to control the view thus creating erratic behavior.